How to combine admin and client side with docker nginx?
I use nodejs mysql sequelize. i have three folder: new-admin, new-client, new-backend. new-admin work 3000 port, new-client 5173 port, new-backend 3001 port. new-client and new-admin these vue apps. new-client have routes: /, /posts, /articles, /login ,... and new-admin have routes: /admin, /login, /admin/posts, /admin/articles, .... and i use docker. i create Dockerdevfile every folder. after I build nginx folder. inside have docker file with nginx configuration:
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

and configuration file:
upstream client {
  server client:5173;
}

upstream api {
  server api:3001;
}

upstream admin {
  server admin:3000;  
}

server {
  listen 80;
   
    location /sockjs-node {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://api;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }


    location /uploads/ {
        
        proxy_pass http://api;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }


    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://api;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

     
    location /login {
       proxy_pass http://client/login;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /admin {
      # rewrite ^/ab(/.*)$ $1 break;
      proxy_pass http://admin;
      
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    
}

problem here if i open login page must show new-client login page. and when i write localhost:8080/admin i want to show admin pages.
version: "3.8"

services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./new-backend/.env
    # ports:
    #   - $MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$DB_DATABASE
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./new-backend
    # volumes:
    #   - /app/node_modules
    #   - ./new-backend/:/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - JWT_SECRET=$JWT_SECRET
      - SESSION_SECRET=$SESSION_SECRET
      - ACCESS_JWT_SECRET=$ACCESS_JWT_SECRET
      - DB_HOST=mysqldb
      - DB_USER=$DB_USERNAME
      - DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD
      - DB_DATABASE=$DB_DATABASE
      - DB_PORT=33060
    develop:
      watch:
        - path: ./new-backend/package.json
          action: rebuild
        - path: ./new-backend/package-lock.json
          action: rebuild
        - path: ./new-backend/
          target: /app
          action: sync

  client:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./new-client
    # volumes:
    #   - /app/node_modules
    #   - ./new-client/:/app
    # environment:
    #   - VITE_API_URL=api
    environment:
      - VITE_API_URL=
    develop:
      watch:
        - path: ./new-client/package.json
          action: rebuild
        - path: ./new-client/package-lock.json
          action: rebuild
        - path: ./new-client/
          target: /app
          action: sync

  admin:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./new-admin
    environment:
      - VITE_API_URL=
    develop:
      watch:
        - path: ./new-admin/package.json
          action: rebuild
        - path: ./new-admin/package-lock.json
          action: rebuild
        - path: ./new-admin/
          target: /app
          action: sync

volumes:
  db:

this is my docker-compose file. problem here admin page dont work. console work. but browser show 502 bad Gateway. why? help me solve this
